# Flex Spark VideoDisplay: rewind seek backward

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex-spark, videodisplay

How could i rewind video back for, let's say, 5 seconds?

I tried `player.seek(player.currentTime - 5)` but this gives no effect except small pauses (like freezing while seeking - while left arrow key is pressed down).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting it to play backwards (just as it does forwards), that is not possible that I have ever seen.

You can try looping it backwards with `.seek()`, but it still wont have a smooth playback experience such as going forwards.

Comment: well, then i should leave it for now... =(

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that OP is asking about rewinding; not playing backward.
As far as I understand 'seek()' looks for the nearest keyframe prior to the requested time. That is why, rewinding by a few seconds may give you unexpected results.
FTQuest